# Running multiple Rails projects on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, multiple-projects

I'm brand new to Rails. I have one Rails project on my machine, but I'd like to create a 2nd project from scratch and I'm having trouble figuring out where and how to set it up. Specifically:

- My current project is located in the Projects/project1 directory. I'd like to have it located in Projects/project2. Do just reinstall Rails into that directory?
- I still need access to project1. How do I switch back and forth between the two projects in terms of browser access? Will it be a separate server? Do I have to edit a file to switch?
- Anything else you think I might need to know in order to manage multiple projects. Please assume that I know nothing about the setup as I'm just getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current project is located in the Projects/project1 directory. I'd like to have it located in Projects/project2. Do just reinstall Rails into that directory?

Just create a new Rails project in that directory by running `rails new`:

```
$ cd Projects
$ rails new project2
```

You'll have a new (empty) Rails application in project2.

> I still need access to project1. How do I switch back and forth between the two projects in terms of browser access? Will it be a separate server? Do I have to edit a file to switch?

Assuming you're running local servers via `rails server`, you can specify which port your server is running on via `-p`.

Given a Rails project, you can listen on `localhost:3001` by executing

```
$ ./script/rails server -p 3001
```

To run multiple Rails projects locally, make sure they're all running on a unique port.

> Anything else you think I might need to know in order to manage multiple projects. Please assume that I know nothing about the setup as I'm just getting started.

Depending on your platform, you should look into [Pow](http://pow.cx/) or [Passenger](http://modrails.com/) which automate the process of deploying multiple Rails apps to a single server.

Comment: So I was able to install the new project fine, but I'm running into trouble with the port instructions. When I run '$ ./script/rails server -p 3001', I get an error: `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: This is an unrelated problem. You'll either want to google for a solution or [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I ended up needing to install some additional gems. Thanks for the help.